# PHPUnit very slow if test fails

Tags: phpunit

When running PHPUnit, if there are no errors it runs in aprox. 6 seconds, nevertheless if there are errors it can take up to 3 or 4 minutes....Only to report the error information.

I'm running PHP version 5.5.3 and PHPUnit version 3.7.28 in Windows.

The tests are painfully simple, even the simplest assertion fail makes the test report take forever.

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function someTest() {
        $this->assertEquals(true, false); // takes forever to report
    }
}
```

Running a database test with --debug I get the following output

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-cms
λ phpunit --debug tests\unit\DatabaseTest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.


Starting test 'DatabaseTest::testCRUD'.
F
Starting test 'DatabaseTest::testRetrieval'.
.

Time: 8.91 seconds, Memory: 2.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) DatabaseTest::testCRUD
Failed asserting that 19 matches expected 18.

D:\xampp\htdocs\blueberry-cms\tests\unit\DatabaseTest.php:37

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 22, Failures: 1.
```

The test runs fine until "There was 1 failure:" then it stops outputting text... stops for like 2 or 3 minutes and then finishes outputting text.

Comment: What kind of logging do you have? Generating report files? Code Coverage?

Comment: I'm using xampp with pretty much default configuration and xdebug, how can I check the logging?

Comment: Why does a simple test like the one above takes `6` seconds on success? That's too much. I guess there is something you missed to tell us

Comment: The test above was an example, my real test makes some file IO, nevertheless, I find the difference between 6 seconds and 3 minutes huge

Comment: I guess it is because the tests reaching some IO timeouts. (when failing).. The reporting effort of PHPUnit is the same for failed or succeeded tests

Comment: It does the same with all tests, not only IO tests. I now added the output Mike B wanted :)

Comment: Is there a `phpunit.dist.xml` in your folder?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I found out a workaround:

1. Download a `.phar` copy of PHPunit and put it in your document root. ([link to phpunit downloads page](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html))
2. Instead of running the `phpunit` command from the php "bin folder" (or wherever you have it in your `$PATH`), run `php phpunit.phar` from the root of my repository.
   Ej: `php phpunit.phar --bootstrap=./tests/bootstrap.php ./tests/`

**Probably this issue can be solved by updating phpunit**.

(In my case (PHP 5.6) the phpunit version in my PHP "bin folder" is `3.7.21`, while the `.phar` I downloaded is version `4.8.36`)

I haven't tested this, but it should work as well:

1. Replace the phpunit version located in your php "bin folder" (or in wherever you have it in your `$PATH`)
2. Now every time you run `phpunit` you will be using the latest version, whithout  having to copy the `.phar` to every new project.